# can I submit an azure log query to get current datetime?

Tags: azure

I can execute the following query in ssms to get the current datetime for a sql server db:

```
select GETDATE()
```

Is there any type of comparable query that I can use to get the current datetime being used within an Azure custom log?  I tried to submit something equivalent through an azure log query but the syntax does not appear to be valid:

```
MyLog_CL
| now()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible, you can use code as blow(you can change the table **Event** to any table like **MyLog_CL**):

```
Event
| extend now=now() // now() is based on utc, you can use now(8h) to specify the time zone as utc+8
| project now
| take 1
```

and note that the now() is based on utc, you can use now(8h) or anyother hours to specify time zone as utc+x(x can be 1,2,3...).

[image]

**And the following are some common usage of now(), if you are interesting, you can take a look.**

When use the now in azure log query, please follow the below instructions:

1.just want to see the current datetime, please use `print method` to print out the datetime:

`print now()` , it will print out the current datetime(utc).

`print now(8h)` , it will print out the current datetime (utc+8).

2.when use now() in a table of azure log, it should be used in a where clause to filter out results:

```
Event
| where TimeGenerated <= now()
```

or

```
Event
| where TimeGenerated <= now(-3h)
```

Screenshot as below just for your reference:

[image]